# How to get the exact quantity of months between two dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

I'm trying to get the quantity of months between two dates

but for some reason, the moment diff method some times returns the correct number and some times is wrong (by one month), (depending on the dates I guess)

```
        var estDate = "some date"; //2022-06-02
        estDate = estDate.toString();
        var estDateYear = estDate.substring(0,4);
        var estDateMonth = estDate.substring(4, 6);
        var estDateDay = estDate.substring(6, 8);

        estDate = estDateYear + '-' + estDateMonth + '-' + estDateDay;

        //first date
        estDate = moment(estDate);


        //actual date
        var date = moment();


        //DIFF
        var diff= date.diff(estDate, 'month'); 
        diff= diff.toString();
```

Any Idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the third argument in the `diff` method to true. This will return fractions of a month instead of a whole number. Then, you can round as needed to return the number you would like.

```
var diff = Math.floor(date.diff(estDate, 'month', true));
```

**Documentation**
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/
`By default, moment#diff will truncate the result to zero decimal places, returning an integer. If you want a floating point number, pass true as the third argument.`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just parse the `estDate` string using `moment` to begin with?

```
var estDate = "2022-06-02"; //2022-06-02
estDate = moment(estDate, "YYYY-MM-DD");

//actual date
var date = moment();

//DIFF
var diff= date.diff(estDate, 'month'); 
diff= diff.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Simply use Momentjs Formation library

//let estDate = "2022-06-02";
let estDate = moment("2022-06-02", "YYYY-MM-DD");
let actualdate = moment();
let diff= actualdate.diff(estDate, 'M'); 
diff= diff.toString();
console.log(diff);
```

```html
<div>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
</div>
```